# Await within a fire-and-forget method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've noticed that when an `await` is within a method which I'm firing and forgetting the app will only make it as far as the `await` then it will act like it hits a `return`. In a simplified version of what I'm currently looking at you may have:

```
public void DoTheThing() {
    ...
    Task fireAndForget = SendAsync(emails);
}

public async Task SendAsync(List<Email> emails) {
    foreach (var email in emails) {
        var to = email.to;
        var body = email.body;
        await EmailSenderAsync(to,body);
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

This will never make it past the line `await EmailSenderAsync(to,body);` and only the very first email in `emails` will be sent. `EmailSenderAsync` is external code so I cannot step into it. Adding an await to `SendAsync(emails)` will make everything work fine... but then it's not fire and forget.

I recognize this probably isn't the best solution for this particular situation. I'm more looking to understand why this fails and what pattern you can use to make an `async` function within a fire and forget work as intended.

Comment: Do you actually see that behavior or is that what you gather from debugging?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's actually seen. The first email in "emails" will actually arrive and a breakpoint on Task.Delay is never hit.

Comment: A breakpoint won't ever be hit because the control is returned to the parent. So, there's no question here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The question is, how do you make it perform as expected? i.e. actually iterate over the foreach.

Comment: It *will* iterate over the foreach *if you don't debug*

Comment: I compiled again under Release and am seeing the same behaviour. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I said if you don't debug, not if you don't build as debug. The code will continue to run on a different thread if you just let it run

Comment: I haven't touched it at all for a couple minutes now and there is only supposed to be 3 seconds between each email. Still- the first is sent and none of the others are. Confirmed with email logging.

Comment: Try to make `SendAsync` `void` instead of `Task`. Also, could that `EmailSenderAsync` have thrown an exception that you don't see due to not awaiting it?

Comment: So this is interesting- Making SendAsync void actually does work! but the request to the server (this is web app kicked off by front end request) is now returning a 500 error. Which makes zero sense because I can see the object before its getting handed back to the front-end and everything is completely fine. What strange world have I stumbled into?

Comment: Sounds like there is an exception in there somewhere. When an unhandled exception occurs in an async void, it blows up *everything* (as opposed to async Task where the exception gets thrown when you await it, and can be handled there). So you need to wrap the whole thing in a try/catch and keep the exceptions from propagating out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem the other day.  What I did was declare my `await` methods as tasks, then pass them to `Task.WhenAll`.

Try this:

```
var taskEmailSendAsync = EmailSenderAsync(to, body);
var taskDelay = Task.Delay(3000);

await Task.WhenAll(taskEmailSenderAsync, taskDelay)
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Camilo mentioned, the control is returning to your parent. Make sure your parent is still there with something like so:

```
var parentContext = Task.Run(() => DoTheThing() );
parentContext .Wait();
```

Comment: This removes the fire-and-forget effect, so this doesn't help